# Update Multiple records in single query MS SQL

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to update multiple records in the table using the temporary table using the below query, but doesn't working. Please tell me the proper way to update multiple records.

```
UPDATE sarufoo 
SET sarufoo.mobile = (SELECT mobile_no FROM logan) 
WHERE sarufoo.homep IN (SELECT homep FROM logan);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One neater way to achieve that be would to join the two tables:

```
UPDATE sf
SET sf.mobile = l.mobile_no
From
    sarufoo sf
    JOIN logan l ON sf.homep = l.homep
```

Comment: And be careful if logan.homep can have multiple records for each sarufoo.homep.

Answer (score 0):

You have to correlate the row you are updating with the row you are selecting from. Otherwise your subselect (the SET one) will return every row it has.

```
UPDATE sarufoo 
SET sarufoo.mobile = (SELECT mobile_no FROM logan WHERE sarufoo.homep = logan.homep) 
WHERE sarufoo.homep IN (SELECT homep FROM logan);
```